# NetLogo If Command

Tags: netlogo

I created an if statement and if this statement is true, I want two commands to be executed, one is in regards to a patch and the other is in regards to the turtles. If this condition is true, I want the patch a turtle is on to decrease a variable of the patch and I also want a variable of the turtle to increase. How would I link the two commands to the same if statement?

Example:

```
if ([patch-variable] of patch-at 0 0) > 0.2

[ask patch-at 0 0

[set patch-variable patch-variable - 0.01]

[ask turtle

  [set turtle-variable turtle-variable + 1 ]]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to put the command into separated square brackets. If the condition is true, Netlogo will execute all commands within the next pair of square brackets.

```
if patch-variable > 0.2

[
  set patch-variable patch-variable - 0.01
  set turtle-variable turtle-variable + 1
]
```

Comment: If the command for the turtle variable was placed above the command for the patch variable would that work as well. The entire chain of procedures is for this specific variable and I want to ensure that only the turtle who has changed a patch variable changes their variable as well.

Comment: I think the solution depends on where you place the if statement. Let's assume, it is in a "turtle context". With `patch-here` you get the patch, the specific turtle is on. I changed it in the answer. Also, if all of the code is executed in a "turtle context", you don't have to ask the turtle.
With "turtle context" I mean if this is in a procedure that is executed after you e.g. `ask turtles[ this-procedure]`

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, in what order you change the turtle's and the patch's variables.

Comment: You don't need to write `[patch-variable] of patch-here`, you can simply write `patch-variable`. A turtle has direct access to the patch variables of the patch it is standing on. Similarly you don't need to the `ask patch-here`.